# Group entries by date and time from timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I'm building a booking system and have opted to use timestamps to store the bookings in my mysql database. The user can book 2 or 3 slots consequtively however, for example:

```
9:00 - 9:30
9:30 - 10:00
10:00 - 10:30
```

or they can just book single slots.

I want to show the bookings made by a user but group them by the time frame, so for example in the times shown above it should show 9:00 - 10:30 instead of listing 3 items.

Each booking is stored with a bookingFrom and bookingUntil as a timetamp. I have managed to get it working for 2 bookings (eg 9:00-9:30 and 9:30-10:00 to show as just 9:00-10:00) but if there is a middle entry, i'm struggling with how to get this working.

Any ideas? I'm using PHP/mySQL

TABLE SCHEMA

bookingID, userID, bookingFrom (INT - unix timestamp), bookingUntil (INT - unix timestamp)

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dma_bookings` (
  `bookingID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bookingFrom` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bookingUntil` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `roomID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookingID`),
  KEY `userID` (`userID`,`bookingFrom`,`bookingUntil`),
  KEY `roomID` (`roomID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=98 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `dma_bookings`
--

INSERT INTO `dma_bookings` (`bookingID`, `userID`, `bookingFrom`, `bookingUntil`, `roomID`) VALUES
(95, 1, 1317362400, 1317364199, 1),
(96, 1, 1317364200, 1317365999, 1),
(97, 1, 1317366000, 1317367799, 1);
```

Code so far (apologies very messy!):

```
$bookingArray = $data['bookingInfo'];
        $bookingCleanArray = array();
        $reversedArray = array_reverse($data['bookingInfo']);
        $currentItemIndex=0;
        $nextItemIndex=1;

        foreach($reversedArray as $booking){
            echo "<hr>BookingID: ".$booking['bookingID']."<br/><br/>";

            $bookingFromMinusOne=$booking['bookingFrom']-1;

            if($bookingFromMinusOne==$data['bookingInfo'][$nextItemIndex]['bookingUntil']){

                //The current booking is part of a multiple booking range
                $bookingArray[$nextItemIndex]['bookingUntil']=$booking['bookingUntil'];
                unset($bookingArray[$currentItemIndex]);
            }else{
                echo "Single booking<br/>";
            }

            $currentItemIndex++;
            $nextItemIndex++;

        }
```

Comment: put some idea of table schema and data and what result u need from query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got separate fields for each time you load them into an array then use the first string and count to find the last string.

But yes as rahularyansharma said needs a bit more detail.

Okay... hhmm
Wouldn't you just want to grab:

```
SELECT dma_bookings (bookingID, userID, bookingFrom, bookingUntil, roomID) WHERE userID = 1)
```

Which should give us:

bookingID, userID, bookingFrom, bookingUntil, roomID

```
 $bookingArray = array( 95, 1, 1317362400, 1317364199, 1 ),
 array( 96, 1, 1317364200, 1317365999, 1 ),
 array( 97, 1, 1317366000, 1317367799, 1 ),
```

so if we...

```
echo  $bookingArray[][2]; we get '1317362400'
$c = count($bookingArray);
echo $bookingArray[$c][3]; we get '1317367799'
```

Or have I completely misunderstood what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stephen. I'm afraid the problem isn't as straight forward as that. Consider a forth entry in the bookings table, which is completely separate to the previous 3 entries (95 96 and 97), although the first three are part of a series (you can see as the bookingUntil (1317364199) from bookingID 95 is followed by 1317364200 from bookingID 96. But, if there is a forth entry, that has a completely different booking for later in the day - 4pm say, it wouldn't work for your solution as it'd show a booking from 8am to 4pm, where it should be 8-9:30 and then 4-4:30

Comment: So we're only grouping the bookings if there boundaries match.
e.g. 9 - 10 and 10 - 11 get grouped as they touch but 9 - 10 and 2 - 3 shouldn't.

(http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

But as we're in a multi-dimensional array we'll probably need a function to shuffle them all into 2 arrays (start and end) then sort them.

I'll give it a crack later... lunch break is over.

Answer (score 0):

I think my approach would be to select all the bookings for a given user, but order the results by the start time. I get the feeling your current loop has the right start, you just need a few more conditions to make sure the slots work.

I would start with the first slot, and keep adjusting the end time until I reach a start time that is greater than the current end time. At that point you finish with the current slot, (say push it onto another array), and set your current slot to the new one.

Here is an example, although I don't have the time to test it I think it should work:

```
$slots = array(
    array('bookingID' => 95, 'userID' => 1, 'bookingFrom' => 1317362400, 'bookingUntil' => 1317364199, 'roomID' => 1), 
    array('bookingID' => 96, 'userID' => 1, 'bookingFrom' => 1317364200, 'bookingUntil' => 1317365999, 'roomID' => 1), 
    array('bookingID' => 97, 'userID' => 1, 'bookingFrom' => 1317366000, 'bookingUntil' => 1317367799, 'roomID' => 1)
);

$condensed_slots = array();
$currentSlot = null;
foreach($slots as $slot){
    if($currentSlot == null) $currentSlot = $slot;
    else {
        if($slot['bookingFrom'] <= $currentSlot['bookingUntil']){
            $currentSlot['bookingUntil'] = $slot['bookingFrom'];
        }
        else {
            $condensed_slots[] = $currentSlot;
            $currentSlot = $slot;
        }
    }
}
```

So after that `$condensed_slots` should contain a reduced set (if possible) of slots, although the bookingID may not necessarily reflect the original `from` and `until` timestamps (obviously).

Comment: As a side note, in your current implementation you want to be careful modifying the array a foreach loop is iterating over while the loop is running. You can end up with all sorts of crazy stuff if you delete an index the loop hasn't reached yet.

Comment: Thanks for that, yeah I thought about that afterwards and I had the data append to a new array that's defined and modified outside of the foreach loop that's iterating. That way i can sort and modify after the iteration has completed without worrying about any nastyness.